# Find all replies to a chat message

Tags: feature-request, chat

Is there a way *or* could it be possible to have a separate page with all the replies to a single message? Would this be a lot of work to implement?

[image: Replies]

Comment: Can you give a use case for that?

Comment: @balpha Summons and super-pings on a user when he goes through the chat history. When currently in the chat room it's definitely not a problem the messages in reply are selected

Comment: @balpha Additionally, since the conversations are disconnected, it would be nice to weed out the messages in between, especially if the conversation takes place in a short amount of time, but in a noisy room, or, if the messages take place over a long period of time (but are still properly linked).  A limit on `x` messages both ways (back and forward) would be reasonable so as not to pull massive chat histories.

Comment: @balpha: I'd like this functionality as well.  The use case is: someone other than me has asked an interesting chat question and I'd like to know if it's got replies (or if it's got other replies if I have replied to it).

Comment: @balpha Use case: I asked some chat users a question a while ago, and I remember they all replied with some delay, but don't remember what. I'd like to find their answers without having to ask them again, and I'm pretty sure they all used the reply feature. (Actually happening right now.) In general it would be useful to reconstruct asynchronous conversations that stretch over hours or days later on, because currently it's impossible to find out if any chat message was ever replied to.